# After Upgrade: An error has happened during application run. See exception log for details

Tags: magento2

After upgrading Magento 2 to the latest version, I started getting the error below each time I try to access the website:

"An error has happened during application run. See exception log for details."

Any suggestion would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: See the log under ‘var’ folder.

Comment: please check var/log/system.log or var/log/exception.log file.

Answer (score 1):

Please run the this command to show the error:

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check in **var/log/system or exception.log**  or **run command php bin/magento cache:flush**

Comment: Thank you all for the support! I tried flushing the cache with the command "php bin/magento cache:flush" via SSH but I'm getting the following error message: "bin/magento must be run as a CLI applicationroot@server

Answer (score 0):

can you check your php version using php -v ?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/179977)

Comment: https://mage2.pro/t/topic/2318 - check this

Comment: Thanks all for your suggestions. I haven't logged for a while. :) But the issue was resolved a longtime ago. :)